# How to use ashmem in native code (without binder)

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-memory, ashmem

Is it possible to use `ashmem` without passing fd through binder?

From my android native code, I am forking two different processes. I want to use shared memory between these two processes while they are executing. How can i achieve it?